# Quotes missing in Hive Query - HQL

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

I am calling HQL from shell script.

I am passing variable to HQL from querying from other table. Variable I am passing as follows:

$$A1=('123','124')

I see variable $$A1 properly in shell script with echo statement and it displayed as ('123','124').

but when I am using this variable in query, its missing single quotes. I mean it is passing as (123,124)

I am passing as $$A1 as follows:

```
select * from table1 where cd in $$A1

query is taking as select * from table where cd in (123,124)
```

why single quotes are missing when it is passing to the query.

appreciate any help on this.

Thanks,
Babu

Comment: You can use sub query instead of querying another table and passing that result to hql ??

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am passing several parameters to HQL and it is very difficult to write sub queries to each variable and I think it impacts performance as well.